# See Data Type of Object

Tags: c#

I am looping through a list of objects. Each object can contain one or more properties. I want to see if the property is either: a string, a numerical value, a boolean, or a Date time.

I did some research and found out to get the property type you can use:

```
object prop in item.GetType().GetProperties();
```

So I updated my looping to:

```
        foreach (var item in myGenericList)
        {
            foreach (object prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                //Combobox
                if (prop.Equals(typeof(string)))
                {
                    GenerateComboBox(prop);
                }
                else if (prop is decimal || prop is int || prop is double)
                {
                    GenerateRangeControl(prop);
                }
                else if (prop is bool)
                {
                    GenerateToggle(prop);
                }
                else if (prop is DateTime)
                {
                    GenerateDatePicker(prop);
                }
            }
        }
```

But none of the conditions are being met. (No if-condition is true)
How can I loop through a generic list of objects and find the data type of each property inside the object?

Comment: I forgot to mention when I do look at the value of the prop in debugging, the value is: {System.String FieldName}

Comment: As per the manual: Returns PropertyInfo[] An array of PropertyInfo objects representing all public properties of the current Type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetProperties` returns the properties themselves, as references `PropertyInfo` objects. A `PropertyInfo` isn't a string, or a decimal etc - it's the property, not the *value* of the property.

If you want to get the *value* of each property, you want something like:

```cs
foreach (var property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var propertyValue = property.GetValue(item);
    // Now use propertyValue
}
```

If you need to ignore setter-only properties (which are really rare) you can do that easily enough via filtering:

```cs
foreach (var property in item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.CanRead))
{
    var propertyValue = property.GetValue(item);
    // Now use propertyValue
}
```

If you don't need the value, just the type, you can use the [`PropertyType` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype?view=netcore-3.1) to determine the type of the property.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I'll flag this as the correct answer as soon as I am allowed to

Comment: @EmilevRooyen It will throw exception, if property has no getter. Also, make sure you actually want to execute the code in the property getter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check [PropertyType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype?view=netcore-3.1):

```
if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
{
    GenerateComboBox(prop);
}
else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(decimal)
    || prop.PropertyType == typeof(int)
    || prop.PropertyType == typeof(double))
{
    GenerateRangeControl(prop);
}
// ... and so on
```